# How do I know if my SSD is SLC or MLC?

Tags: linux, ssd

I have 3 SSDs on my server. How can I tell if they are SLC or MLC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would search their part number (see the content of `/sys/class/block/sd<x>/device/model`) in a web search engine next to `SLC` or `MLC`, as I don't think that kind of information is exposed to the operating system and thus may not be queried automatically.

Comment: root@host [~]# cat /sys/class/block/sdb/device/model
SAMSUNG SSD 830
root@host [~]# cat /sys/class/block/sdc/device/model
M4-CT256M4SSD2
root@host [~]#